# MediaPlayer error when attempt to play from a stream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Does anybody know what does the second argument mean from this error **(1, -2147483648)** in MediaPlayer? I constantly receive it when attempting to play an audio from a url stream. I try to play it from a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter if that matter. I have already reviewed this post [Android MediaPlayer error: MediaPlayer error(1, -2147483648) on Stream from internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795388/android-mediaplayer-error-mediaplayer-error1-2147483648-on-stream-from-inte) however all the answers refers to the stream support issues. It's not a stream support issue in my case since I am able to play an audio from the same stream but just using a different class. This is a method that I'm using for playing:

```
private void startPlaying(String fileName) {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {  // Read a file from a fileInputStream from a filesystem (EXTERNAL OR INTERNAL storage)
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
            Log.d("MediaPlayer is playing", "from device");

        } else {
    //      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getFilePath());   // Read a file from a url
            Log.d("MediaPlayer is playing", "from stream");             
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new CompletionListener());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: Make sure you do mediaPLayer.release() before starting a new mediaPlayer (which you do at the beginning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is usually one of these in this case:

1. File path is in error. Incorrect directory or Url or Uri found.
2. Media file is in error, incompatible format.
3. Missing permissions

Here's a good blog that outlines these situations and how to fix them:

http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988

Also see this thread:

[Android mediaplayer MediaPlayer(658): error (1, -2147483648)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236095/android-mediaplayer-mediaplayer658-error-1-2147483648?rq=1)

Comment: File path is in error - I haven't noticed that I placed file extension twice. Thanks for the help!