# Restart video when user come back on activity, It shows MediaPlayer(15228): error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I'm playing video in home screen by using TextureView, but when I'm going to other activity and stay for long time means more than video length and come back to home activity then its showing blank video screen.

```
private TextureVideoView customVideoView;
```

In `onCreate()`:

```
customVideoView = (TextureVideoView) findViewById(R.id.customvideoview);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.home_video;
         customVideoView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         customVideoView.setDataSource(mContext, Uri.parse(path));
//       customVideoView.setLooping(true);
```

In `onResume()`:

```
if(customVideoView!=null){
    customVideoView.play();
}
customVideoView.play();
```

TextureVideoView class code:

```
public class TextureVideoView extends TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
    Context context;

    // Indicate if logging is on
    public static final boolean LOG_ON = true;

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = TextureVideoView.class.getName();

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private float mVideoHeight;
    private float mVideoWidth;

    private boolean mIsDataSourceSet;
    private boolean mIsViewAvailable;
    private boolean mIsVideoPrepared;
    private boolean mIsPlayCalled;

    private ScaleType mScaleType;
    private State mState;

    public enum ScaleType {
        CENTER_CROP, TOP, BOTTOM
    }

    public enum State {
        UNINITIALIZED, PLAY, STOP, PAUSE, END
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
        initView();
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context=context;
        initView();
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context=context;
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        initPlayer();
        setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        mScaleType = scaleType;
    }

    private void updateTextureViewSize() {
        float viewWidth = getWidth();
        float viewHeight = getHeight();

        float scaleX = 1.0f;
        float scaleY = 1.0f;

        if (mVideoWidth > viewWidth && mVideoHeight > viewHeight) {
            scaleX = mVideoWidth / viewWidth;
            scaleY = mVideoHeight / viewHeight;
        } else if (mVideoWidth < viewWidth && mVideoHeight < viewHeight) {
            scaleY = viewWidth / mVideoWidth;
            scaleX = viewHeight / mVideoHeight;
        } else if (viewWidth > mVideoWidth) {
            scaleY = (viewWidth / mVideoWidth) / (viewHeight / mVideoHeight);
        } else if (viewHeight > mVideoHeight) {
            scaleX = (viewHeight / mVideoHeight) / (viewWidth / mVideoWidth);
        }

        // Calculate pivot points, in our case crop from center
        int pivotPointX;
        int pivotPointY;

        switch (mScaleType) {
            case TOP:
                pivotPointX = 0;
                pivotPointY = 0;
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                pivotPointX = (int) (viewWidth);
                pivotPointY = (int) (viewHeight);
                break;
            case CENTER_CROP:
                pivotPointX = (int) (viewWidth / 2);
                pivotPointY = (int) (viewHeight / 2);
                break;
            default:
                pivotPointX = (int) (viewWidth / 2);
                pivotPointY = (int) (viewHeight / 2);
                break;
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);

        setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private void initPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = getMediaPlayer(context);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        mIsVideoPrepared = false;
        mIsPlayCalled = false;
        mState = State.UNINITIALIZED;
    }

    /**
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer#setDataSource(String)
     */
    public void setDataSource(String path) {
        initPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mIsDataSourceSet = true;
            prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer#setDataSource(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)
     */
    public void setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri) {
        initPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mIsDataSourceSet = true;
            prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)
     */
    public void setDataSource(AssetFileDescriptor afd) {
        initPlayer();

        try {
            long startOffset = afd.getStartOffset();
            long length = afd.getLength();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), startOffset, length);
            mIsDataSourceSet = true;
            prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void prepare() {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                            mVideoWidth = width;
                            mVideoHeight = height;
                            updateTextureViewSize();
                        }
                    }
            );
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mState = State.END;
                    log("Video has ended.");

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onVideoEnd();
                    }
                }
            });

            // don't forget to call MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() method when you use constructor for
            // creating MediaPlayer
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mIsVideoPrepared = true;
//                    if (mIsPlayCalled && mIsViewAvailable) {
                        log("Player is prepared and play() was called.");
                        play();
//                    }

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onVideoPrepared();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Play or resume video. Video will be played as soon as view is available and media player is
     * prepared.
     *
     * If video is stopped or ended and play() method was called, video will start over.
     */
    public void play() {
        if (!mIsDataSourceSet) {
            log("play() was called but data source was not set.");
            return;
        }

        mIsPlayCalled = true;

        if (!mIsVideoPrepared) {
            log("play() was called but video is not prepared yet, waiting.");
            return;
        }

        if (!mIsViewAvailable) {
            log("play() was called but view is not available yet, waiting.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.PLAY) {
            log("play() was called but video is already playing.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.PAUSE) {
            log("play() was called but video is paused, resuming.");
            mState = State.PLAY;
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.END || mState == State.STOP) {
            log("play() was called but video already ended, starting over.");
            mState = State.PLAY;
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            return;
        }

        mState = State.PLAY;
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    /**
     * Pause video. If video is already paused, stopped or ended nothing will happen.
     */
    public void pause() {
        if (mState == State.PAUSE) {
            log("pause() was called but video already paused.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.STOP) {
            log("pause() was called but video already stopped.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.END) {
            log("pause() was called but video already ended.");
            return;
        }

        mState = State.PAUSE;
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop video (pause and seek to beginning). If video is already stopped or ended nothing will
     * happen.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (mState == State.STOP) {
            log("stop() was called but video already stopped.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.END) {
            log("stop() was called but video already ended.");
            return;
        }

        mState = State.STOP;
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer#setLooping(boolean)
     */
    public void setLooping(boolean looping) {
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(looping);
    }

    /**
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer#seekTo(int)
     */
    public void seekTo(int milliseconds) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(milliseconds);
    }

    /**
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer#getDuration()
     */
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    static void log(String message) {
        if (LOG_ON) {
            Log.d(TAG, message);
        }
    }

    private MediaPlayerListener mListener;

    /**
     * Listener trigger 'onVideoPrepared' and `onVideoEnd` events
     */
    public void setListener(MediaPlayerListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface MediaPlayerListener {

        public void onVideoPrepared();

        public void onVideoEnd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mIsViewAvailable = true;
        if (mIsDataSourceSet && mIsPlayCalled && mIsVideoPrepared) {
            log("View is available and play() was called.");
            play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }

    static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(Context context){

        MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return mediaplayer;
        }

        try {
            Class<?> cMediaTimeProvider = Class.forName( "android.media.MediaTimeProvider" );
            Class<?> cSubtitleController = Class.forName( "android.media.SubtitleController" );
            Class<?> iSubtitleControllerAnchor = Class.forName( "android.media.SubtitleController$Anchor" );
            Class<?> iSubtitleControllerListener = Class.forName( "android.media.SubtitleController$Listener" );

            Constructor constructor = cSubtitleController.getConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class, cMediaTimeProvider, iSubtitleControllerListener});

            Object subtitleInstance = constructor.newInstance(context, null, null);

            Field f = cSubtitleController.getDeclaredField("mHandler");

            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                f.set(subtitleInstance, new Handler());
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {return mediaplayer;}
            finally {
                f.setAccessible(false);
            }

            Method setsubtitleanchor = mediaplayer.getClass().getMethod("setSubtitleAnchor", cSubtitleController, iSubtitleControllerAnchor);

            setsubtitleanchor.invoke(mediaplayer, subtitleInstance, null);
            //Log.e("", "subtitle is setted :p");
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return mediaplayer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to reinitialize the texture view..Do this in onResume method before playing video

---

```
 String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.home_video;
     customVideoView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     customVideoView.setDataSource(mContext, Uri.parse(path));
```

then do customVideoView.play(); It should work now..

1. File path is in error.
2. Incorrect directory or Url or Uri not found.
3. Media file is in error, incompatible format
4. Missing permissions

See this might solve ur problem [here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995668/mediaplayer-error-when-attempt-to-play-from-a-stream)

Comment: @UjjwalKatiyar hi can you post your onResume method

Comment: @UjjwalKatiyar i edited my answer can you check now :)

Comment: Hi its working, after re initializing texture view in onResume every time.